# Python matplotlib MAXTICKS

Tags: matplotlib, python-3.6

Good Day,

I am getting an error "exceeds Locator.MAXTICKS" on a data set that has seven variables with 42 data elements. I had the code working in a program that was not following object-oriented design.  I am in the process of converting the application to be GUI based. I have created a class and moved the code and since then it has been throwing "RuntimeError: Locator attempting to generate 32146 ticks from 729937.416667 to 733955.541667: exceeds Locator.MAXTICKS" I get the same errors on both my Raspberry Pi and my Ubuntu Desktop.

The Attached code has the extracted Class and sample data. Any an all comments are welcome.

My Platforms are Ubuntu 17.10, Python 3.6.3 and Raspberry Pi (Raspbian) Linux PSensor 4.9.59-v7+ #1047 SMP Sun Oct 29 12:19:23 GMT 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux, Python 3.5.3

Development IntelliJ IDEA on Ubuntu.

*** The Code with the error follow ***

```
import os
import sys
import math
import time
import queue
import shutil
import sqlite3
import datetime
import threading
import subprocess
import tkinter as tk
import random
# Imports required for graphing and animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style
from matplotlib import dates
# import pydevd
# pydevd.settrace('E6500', port=35550, stdoutToServer=True, stderrToServer=True)


class GraphHighResData:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.graph_time = {1: 736766.3923638267, 2: 736766.3924804361, 3: 736766.39259627, 4: 736766.3927130954,
                           5: 736766.3928300098, 6: 736766.392950463, 7: 736766.3930666025, 8: 736766.393182508,
                           9: 736766.3932990318, 10: 736766.3934159958, 11: 736766.3935324071, 12: 736766.3936481519,
                           13: 736766.3937671528, 14: 736766.3938833614, 15: 736766.3939997947, 16: 736766.3941165558,
                           17: 736766.3942329598, 18: 736766.3943496092, 19: 736766.3944654141, 20: 736766.3945822782,
                           21: 736766.3946988309, 22: 736766.3948209379, 23: 736766.3949371425, 24: 736766.3950537147,
                           25: 736766.3951707256, 26: 736766.3952868865, 27: 736766.3954027233, 28: 736766.3955201278,
                           29: 736766.3956363278, 30: 736766.3957529722, 31: 736766.3958699458, 32: 736766.3959858529,
                           33: 736766.3961021379, 34: 736766.3962191116, 35: 736766.3963360166, 36: 736766.3964528549,
                           37: 736766.3965698254, 38: 736766.3966866663, 39: 736766.3968026235, 40: 736766.3969192731,
                           41: 736766.3970411472, 42: 736766.3971574705}

        self.graph_buffer = [{'Sensor2': 75.009, 'Sensor1': 75.519, 'Humidity': 44.0, 'PrimaryKey': '2018:03:13-09:25:00',
             'Temp': 69.8, 'TimeDiff': 10.042438983917236, 'TimeStat': 1520958300.234634, 'CCD': 57.7,
             'TargetTemp': 77.79, 'Pressure': 13.2193},
            {'Sensor2': 75.009, 'Sensor1': 75.519, 'Humidity': 43.0, 'PrimaryKey': '2018:03:13-09:25:10',
             'Temp': 69.8, 'TimeDiff': 10.075046062469482, 'TimeStat': 1520958310.30968, 'CCD': 58.1,
             'TargetTemp': 77.69, 'Pressure': 13.1291},
            {'Sensor2': 75.519, 'Sensor1': 75.519, 'Humidity': 44.0, 'PrimaryKey': '2018:03:13-09:25:20', 'Temp': 69.8, 'TimeDiff': 10.008047103881836, 'TimeStat': 1520958320.317727, 'CCD': 58.1, 'TargetTemp': 77.69, 'Pressure': 13.1291},
            {'Sensor2': 75.009, 'Sensor1': 75.519, 'Humidity': 44.0, 'PrimaryKey': '2018:03:13-09:25:30', 'Temp': 69.8, 'TimeDiff': 10.093719005584717, 'TimeStat': 1520958330.411446, 'CCD': 58.2, 'TargetTemp': 77.69, 'Pressure': 13.2193},
            {'Sensor2': 75.009, 'Sensor1': 75.519, 'Humidity': 44.0, 'PrimaryKey': '2018:03:13-09:25:40', 'Temp': 69.8, 'TimeDiff': 10.101396799087524, 'TimeStat': 1520958340.512843, 'CCD': 58.3, 'TargetTemp': 77.69, 'Pressure': 13.1742},
            {'Sensor2': 75.009, 'Sensor1': 75.519, 'Humidity': 44.0, 'PrimaryKey': '2018:03:13-09:25:50', 'Temp': 69.8, 'TimeDiff': 10.407163143157959, 'TimeStat': 1520958350.920006, 'CCD': 58.4, 'TargetTemp': 77.1, 'Pressure': 12.9938},
            {'Sensor2': 75.009, 'Sensor1': 75.519, 'Humidity': 44.0, 'PrimaryKey': '2018:03:13-09:26:00', 'Temp': 69.8, 'TimeDiff': 10.034451007843018, 'TimeStat': 1520958360.954457, 'CCD': 58.5, 'TargetTemp': 77.69, 'Pressure': 13.084},
            {'Sensor2': 75.009, 'Sensor1': 75.519, 'Humidity': 44.0, 'PrimaryKey': '2018:03:13-09:26:10', 'Temp': 69.8, 'TimeDiff': 10.014230012893677, 'TimeStat': 1520958370.968687, 'CCD': 58.4, 'TargetTemp': 77.69, 'Pressure': 13.1291},
            {'Sensor2': 75.009, 'Sensor1': 75.519, 'Humidity': 44.0, 'PrimaryKey': '2018:03:13-09:26:21', 'Temp': 69.8, 'TimeDiff': 10.06765604019165, 'TimeStat': 1520958381.036343, 'CCD': 58.8, 'TargetTemp': 77.79, 'Pressure': 13.1742},
            {'Sensor2': 75.009, 'Sensor1': 75.519, 'Humidity': 44.0, 'PrimaryKey': '2018:03:13-09:26:31', 'Temp': 71.6, 'TimeDiff': 10.10568881034851, 'TimeStat': 1520958391.142032, 'CCD': 59.0, 'TargetTemp': 77.79, 'Pressure': 13.2193},
            {'Sensor2': 75.519, 'Sensor1': 75.519, 'Humidity': 44.0, 'PrimaryKey': '2018:03:13-09:26:41', 'Temp': 69.8, 'TimeDiff': 10.057940006256104, 'TimeStat': 1520958401.199972, 'CCD': 59.1, 'TargetTemp': 77.79, 'Pressure': 13.1291},
            {'Sensor2': 75.009, 'Sensor1': 75.009, 'Humidity': 44.0, 'PrimaryKey': '2018:03:13-09:26:51', 'Temp': 69.8, 'TimeDiff': 10.000355005264282, 'TimeStat': 1520958411.200327, 'CCD': 59.4, 'TargetTemp': 77.59, 'Pressure': 12.8133},
            {'Sensor2': 75.009, 'Sensor1': 75.519, 'Humidity': 43.0, 'PrimaryKey': '2018:03:13-09:27:01', 'Temp': 69.8, 'TimeDiff': 10.28167200088501, 'TimeStat': 1520958421.481999, 'CCD': 59.7, 'TargetTemp': 77.79, 'Pressure': 13.1742},
            {'Sensor2': 75.009, 'Sensor1': 75.519, 'Humidity': 45.0, 'PrimaryKey': '2018:03:13-09:27:11', 'Temp': 69.8, 'TimeDiff': 10.040425062179565, 'TimeStat': 1520958431.522424, 'CCD': 59.9, 'TargetTemp': 77.79, 'Pressure': 13.1742},
            {'Sensor2': 75.519, 'Sensor1': 75.519, 'Humidity': 44.0, 'PrimaryKey': '2018:03:13-09:27:21', 'Temp': 69.8, 'TimeDiff': 10.059844970703125, 'TimeStat': 1520958441.582269, 'CCD': 60.1, 'TargetTemp': 77.79, 'Pressure': 12.9486},
            {'Sensor2': 75.519, 'Sensor1': 75.519, 'Humidity': 44.0, 'PrimaryKey': '2018:03:13-09:27:31', 'Temp': 69.8, 'TimeDiff': 10.088149070739746, 'TimeStat': 1520958451.670418, 'CCD': 60.4, 'TargetTemp': 77.98, 'Pressure': 13.1291},
            {'Sensor2': 75.519, 'Sensor1': 75.519, 'Humidity': 43.0, 'PrimaryKey': '2018:03:13-09:27:41', 'Temp': 71.6, 'TimeDiff': 10.057312965393066, 'TimeStat': 1520958461.727731, 'CCD': 60.6, 'TargetTemp': 77.69, 'Pressure': 13.1742},
            {'Sensor2': 75.519, 'Sensor1': 75.519, 'Humidity': 44.0, 'PrimaryKey': '2018:03:13-09:27:51', 'Temp': 69.8, 'TimeDiff': 10.078504085540771, 'TimeStat': 1520958471.806235, 'CCD': 60.9, 'TargetTemp': 77.79, 'Pressure': 13.1742},
            {'Sensor2': 75.009, 'Sensor1': 75.519, 'Humidity': 44.0, 'PrimaryKey': '2018:03:13-09:28:01', 'Temp': 69.8, 'TimeDiff': 10.005539894104004, 'TimeStat': 1520958481.811775, 'CCD': 61.6, 'TargetTemp': 77.79, 'Pressure': 13.2645},
            {'Sensor2': 75.519, 'Sensor1': 75.519, 'Humidity': 44.0, 'PrimaryKey': '2018:03:13-09:28:11', 'Temp': 71.6, 'TimeDiff': 10.09705901145935, 'TimeStat': 1520958491.908834, 'CCD': 61.3, 'TargetTemp': 77.69, 'Pressure': 13.0389},
            {'Sensor2': 76.526, 'Sensor1': 75.519, 'Humidity': 45.0, 'PrimaryKey': '2018:03:13-09:28:21', 'Temp': 69.8, 'TimeDiff': 10.070152044296265, 'TimeStat': 1520958501.978986, 'CCD': 61.5, 'TargetTemp': 78.08, 'Pressure': 13.1742},
            {'Sensor2': 75.519, 'Sensor1': 75.519, 'Humidity': 45.0, 'PrimaryKey': '2018:03:13-09:28:32', 'Temp': 69.8, 'TimeDiff': 10.55004596710205, 'TimeStat': 1520958512.529032, 'CCD': 61.7, 'TargetTemp': 77.79, 'Pressure': 13.1291},
            {'Sensor2': 75.009, 'Sensor1': 75.519, 'Humidity': 44.0, 'PrimaryKey': '2018:03:13-09:28:42', 'Temp': 69.8, 'TimeDiff': 10.040081977844238, 'TimeStat': 1520958522.569114, 'CCD': 61.7, 'TargetTemp': 77.69, 'Pressure': 13.1291},
            {'Sensor2': 75.519, 'Sensor1': 75.519, 'Humidity': 45.0, 'PrimaryKey': '2018:03:13-09:28:52', 'Temp': 69.8, 'TimeDiff': 10.071845054626465, 'TimeStat': 1520958532.640959, 'CCD': 61.9, 'TargetTemp': 77.79, 'Pressure': 13.1291},
            {'Sensor2': 75.519, 'Sensor1': 75.519, 'Humidity': 44.0, 'PrimaryKey': '2018:03:13-09:29:02', 'Temp': 71.6, 'TimeDiff': 10.109732866287231, 'TimeStat': 1520958542.750692, 'CCD': 61.5, 'TargetTemp': 77.79, 'Pressure': 13.0389},
            {'Sensor2': 75.519, 'Sensor1': 75.519, 'Humidity': 44.0, 'PrimaryKey': '2018:03:13-09:29:12', 'Temp': 71.6, 'TimeDiff': 10.036301136016846, 'TimeStat': 1520958552.786993, 'CCD': 61.9, 'TargetTemp': 77.79, 'Pressure': 13.084},
            {'Sensor2': 75.519, 'Sensor1': 75.519, 'Humidity': 44.0, 'PrimaryKey': '2018:03:13-09:29:22', 'Temp': 71.6, 'TimeDiff': 10.008300065994263, 'TimeStat': 1520958562.795293, 'CCD': 61.9, 'TargetTemp': 77.79, 'Pressure': 13.1291},
            {'Sensor2': 75.519, 'Sensor1': 75.519, 'Humidity': 44.0, 'PrimaryKey': '2018:03:13-09:29:32', 'Temp': 69.8, 'TimeDiff': 10.143747806549072, 'TimeStat': 1520958572.939041, 'CCD': 62.0, 'TargetTemp': 77.79, 'Pressure': 13.1742},
            {'Sensor2': 75.519, 'Sensor1': 75.519, 'Humidity': 44.0, 'PrimaryKey': '2018:03:13-09:29:42', 'Temp': 71.6, 'TimeDiff': 10.039679050445557, 'TimeStat': 1520958582.97872, 'CCD': 62.0, 'TargetTemp': 78.08, 'Pressure': 13.1742},
            {'Sensor2': 75.519, 'Sensor1': 75.519, 'Humidity': 44.0, 'PrimaryKey': '2018:03:13-09:29:53', 'Temp': 69.8, 'TimeDiff': 10.078082084655762, 'TimeStat': 1520958593.056802, 'CCD': 62.1, 'TargetTemp': 77.69, 'Pressure': 13.1291},
            {'Sensor2': 75.519, 'Sensor1': 75.519, 'Humidity': 43.0, 'PrimaryKey': '2018:03:13-09:30:03', 'Temp': 69.8, 'TimeDiff': 10.106514930725098, 'TimeStat': 1520958603.163317, 'CCD': 62.0, 'TargetTemp': 77.69, 'Pressure': 13.2193},
            {'Sensor2': 75.519, 'Sensor1': 75.519, 'Humidity': 43.0, 'PrimaryKey': '2018:03:13-09:30:13', 'Temp': 69.8, 'TimeDiff': 10.014378070831299, 'TimeStat': 1520958613.177695, 'CCD': 61.8, 'TargetTemp': 77.79, 'Pressure': 12.9938},
            {'Sensor2': 75.519, 'Sensor1': 75.519, 'Humidity': 44.0, 'PrimaryKey': '2018:03:13-09:30:23', 'Temp': 69.8, 'TimeDiff': 10.047011852264404, 'TimeStat': 1520958623.224707, 'CCD': 61.8, 'TargetTemp': 77.79, 'Pressure': 13.1291},
            {'Sensor2': 76.025, 'Sensor1': 75.519, 'Humidity': 44.0, 'PrimaryKey': '2018:03:13-09:30:33', 'Temp': 69.8, 'TimeDiff': 10.10653305053711, 'TimeStat': 1520958633.33124, 'CCD': 61.9, 'TargetTemp': 77.69, 'Pressure': 13.1742},
            {'Sensor2': 75.519, 'Sensor1': 75.519, 'Humidity': 44.0, 'PrimaryKey': '2018:03:13-09:30:43', 'Temp': 69.8, 'TimeDiff': 10.100595951080322, 'TimeStat': 1520958643.431836, 'CCD': 61.8, 'TargetTemp': 77.79, 'Pressure': 13.1742},
            {'Sensor2': 75.519, 'Sensor1': 75.519, 'Humidity': 44.0, 'PrimaryKey': '2018:03:13-09:30:53', 'Temp': 69.8, 'TimeDiff': 10.094821214675903, 'TimeStat': 1520958653.526657, 'CCD': 61.7, 'TargetTemp': 78.18, 'Pressure': 13.1291},
            {'Sensor2': 75.519, 'Sensor1': 75.519, 'Humidity': 44.0, 'PrimaryKey': '2018:03:13-09:31:03', 'Temp': 69.8, 'TimeDiff': 10.106254816055298, 'TimeStat': 1520958663.632912, 'CCD': 61.6, 'TargetTemp': 77.79, 'Pressure': 13.1742},
            {'Sensor2': 75.519, 'Sensor1': 75.519, 'Humidity': 44.0, 'PrimaryKey': '2018:03:13-09:31:13', 'Temp': 71.6, 'TimeDiff': 10.095057010650635, 'TimeStat': 1520958673.727969, 'CCD': 61.6, 'TargetTemp': 77.79, 'Pressure': 13.2193},
            {'Sensor2': 75.009, 'Sensor1': 75.519, 'Humidity': 44.0, 'PrimaryKey': '2018:03:13-09:31:23', 'Temp': 69.8, 'TimeDiff': 10.018701076507568, 'TimeStat': 1520958683.74667, 'CCD': 61.6, 'TargetTemp': 77.79, 'Pressure': 12.9486},
            {'Sensor2': 75.519, 'Sensor1': 75.519, 'Humidity': 44.0, 'PrimaryKey': '2018:03:13-09:31:33', 'Temp': 71.6, 'TimeDiff': 10.07852292060852, 'TimeStat': 1520958693.825193, 'CCD': 61.6, 'TargetTemp': 77.79, 'Pressure': 13.1742},
            {'Sensor2': 75.519, 'Sensor1': 75.519, 'Humidity': 44.0, 'PrimaryKey': '2018:03:13-09:31:44', 'Temp': 69.8, 'TimeDiff': 10.529932022094727, 'TimeStat': 1520958704.355125, 'CCD': 61.6, 'TargetTemp': 77.69, 'Pressure': 13.2193},
            {'Sensor2': 75.519, 'Sensor1': 75.519, 'Humidity': 44.0, 'PrimaryKey': '2018:03:13-09:31:54', 'Temp': 69.8, 'TimeDiff': 10.050326108932495, 'TimeStat': 1520958714.405451, 'CCD': 61.6, 'TargetTemp': 77.79, 'Pressure': 13.1742}]
        # Define variables need for SQLite access here
        self.start_opt = {}
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            self.start_opt[key] = value

        self.db_file = self.start_opt["dbName"]
        self.db_table = self.start_opt["dbTable"]
        self.debug_flag_1 = int(self.start_opt["DebugLevel"]) & 1
        self.debug_flag_2 = int(self.start_opt["DebugLevel"]) & 2
        self.debug_flag_3 = int(self.start_opt["DebugLevel"]) & 4
        self.debug_flag_4 = int(self.start_opt["DebugLevel"]) & 8
        self.total_render_freq = self.start_opt["RenderFreq"]
        self.total_buffer_size = 0
        self.graph_flag = False
        self.total_rec = 0
        self.graph_thread_active = False
        self.db_rec = {"TimeStat": "", "TimeDiff": 0, "Temp": 0, "Humidity": 0, "Sensor1": 0,
                       "Sensor2": 0, "CCD": 0, "Pressure": 0, "TargetTemp": 0, "PrimaryKey": ""}
        self.db_rec_type = {"TimeStat": "Date", "TimeDiff": "Numeric", "Temp": "Numeric", "Humidity": "Numeric",
                            "Sensor1": "Numeric", "Sensor2": "Numeric", "CCD": "Numeric", "Pressure": "Numeric",
                            "TargetTemp": "Numeric", "PrimaryKey": "Text"}
        if self.debug_flag_2:
            print("In GraphHighResData:{}".format(self.start_opt))
        #
        self.fig, self.ax1 = plt.subplots()
        style.use('ggplot')
        plt.title("Pool Sensors: Temperature, Humidity, Sun light Intensity")
        plt.autoscale(enable=False, axis='x')
        plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='y')
        plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
        plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.18)
        self.ax1.clear()
        self.date_format = dates.DateFormatter("%m/%d %H:%M")
        self.ax1.set_ylabel('Temperature & Humidity 0-110 *F', color='g')
        self.ax1.set_ylim(0, 110, auto=False)
        self.ax1.xaxis.axis_date("US/Pacific")
        self.ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(dates.HourLocator(interval=3))
        self.ax1.xaxis.set_minor_locator(dates.HourLocator(interval=1))
        self.ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(self.date_format)
        #   self.temp_view = dates.date2num(timeDV) dates.num2date
        self.low_res_file = self.start_opt["HResImage"]
        self.high_res_file = self.start_opt["LResImage"]

    def animate(self):
        pass

    def graph_block(self):
        if self.debug_flag_2:
            print("PSensorV2: Graph Block {}".format(self.graph_buffer))
        #
        record_cnt = 0
        for rec_in_buffer in self.graph_buffer:
            record_cnt = record_cnt + 1
            temp_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(rec_in_buffer["TimeStat"])
            self.graph_time[record_cnt] = dates.date2num(temp_time)
            if self.debug_flag_2:
                print("PSensorV2: Get Time {}:{}\n({})({})".format(record_cnt, rec_in_buffer,
                                                                   self.graph_time[record_cnt], temp_time))

        plt.ion()
        buff_size = len(self.graph_buffer)
        temp_rec = {}
        ccd_data = {}
        target_temp = {}
        sensor1 = {}
        sensor2 = {}
        temp = {}
        humid = {}
        pressure = {}
        if self.debug_flag_2:
            print("PSensorV2: Pre-Animate ({})\n{}\n{}".format(buff_size, self.graph_time, self.graph_buffer))
        for i in range(buff_size):
            temp_rec = self.graph_buffer[i]
            ccd_data[i] = temp_rec["CCD"]
            target_temp[i] = temp_rec["TargetTemp"]
            sensor1[i] = temp_rec["Sensor1"]
            sensor2[i] =  temp_rec["Sensor2"]
            temp[i] = temp_rec["Temp"]
            humid[i] = temp_rec["Humidity"]
            pressure[i] = temp_rec["Pressure"]

        self.ax1.plot(xdata=self.graph_time, ydata=ccd_data, c='b', ls='--', label='Sun Intensity')
        self.ax1.plot(xdata=self.graph_time, ydata=target_temp , c='y', ls='.', label='Target Temp')
        self.ax1.plot(xdata=self.graph_time, ydata=sensor1, c='c', label='Inlet Temp')
        self.ax1.plot(xdata=self.graph_time, ydata=sensor2, c='r', label='Outlet Temp')
        self.ax1.plot(xdata=self.graph_time, ydata=temp, c='g', label='System Temp')
        self.ax1.plot(xdata=self.graph_time, ydata=humid, c='g', ls='-.', label='Humidity')
        self.ax1.plot(xdata=self.graph_time, ydata=pressure, c='b', ls=':', label="Pressure")
        plt.legend(fontsize='x-small', loc='upper left')
        # animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.animate, interval=1000, repeat_delay=5000, blit=True)
        print("Show")
        plt.show()
        print("Save Low")
        plt.savefig(self.low_res_file, dpi=600, transparent=False)
        print("Save High")
        plt.savefig(self.high_res_file, dpi=1200, transparent=False)
        # plt.show()
        print("Draw")
        plt.draw()
        return 0


# ###############
startup_options = {'RenderFreq': 5, 'HResImage': '/home/jcfowler/Desktop/HResImage.jpg', 'LoopWaitTime': 15,
                   'dbName': '/mnt/home/DB/PoolHighResTemps.db', 'TotalWriteCnt': 30,
                   'DebugLevel': '3', 'dbTable': 'HighResTemps', 'TotalCellCnt': 5760,
                   'LResImage': '/home/jcfowler/Desktop/LResImage.jpg'}
# Start Test Program
graph_data = GraphHighResData(**startup_options)
test_object=graph_data.graph_block()
time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] if you want help here. What is `/home/jcfowler/Desktop/HResImage.jpg`?

Comment: That is the expected saved image from the plotted graph.

Comment: The attached code will reproduce the problem.  If it works on another system then the problem is on my Ubuntu and Raspberry Pi devices.

Comment: No, you definitely have a problem with the code, not with the system. But you should provide a [mcve] that can be run on another system. As it stands it will cost me half an hour to actually understand what the plot should show, while the problem may be solved using a single line of code or so.

Answer (score 0):

matplotlib is throwing the Locator.MAXTICKS error whenever it does not like the data it has received. I reduced the code to take the data structure and copy it into a numby array and it would graph the data. When I moved that code to my GUI application it would display the graph the first time and fail on subsequent passes.  Throwing the MAXTICKS error every time.

I removed all of the matplotlib code from my GUI and replaced it with ten lines of code from pygal and saving the graph to a temp file. Then display that file at the push of a button. Works everytime. Simpler is better.